# Why does my toilet make a high pitched whine when it refills?

Tags: plumbing, water, toilet

When my toilet is refilling with water,it makes a very high pitched whine.  Any suggestions on how to resolve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on the age of the toilet mechanism, you may have an easy fix. If it is a partially clogged valve (as suggested in the comment by *ratchet freak*) and if it is one of the newer type units, the upper part of the valve can be easily accessed.

Many toilet filler valves look something like [this one](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Fluidmaster-Universal-Fill-Valve-400ARP25/100554467#.UjX7OMaKIuc)

[image: toilet valve]

The top cap comes off these valves, usually by pressing down slightly with your palm and rotating counterclockwise. Immediately below the cap is usually a strainer filter that can get clogged. Cleaning this out usually solves the problem. Then just reinstall the cap.

If you have a different type of valve, you need to ascertain whether that is where the noise is coming from. With the lid off the tank, you may be able to confirm the source of the sound. If it is the valve, you may be able to determine what part of the mechanism is causing the obstruction.

If the cause is the valve, but the cure is not readily apparent, it probably is worth changing the mechanism, which is cheap and fairly easily done. The repair kits have complete instructions and basically involve

- turning off the water supply
- draining the tank
- uncoupling the supply line from the bottom of the mechanism
- unscrewing the nut that holds the mechanism on (from the outside bottom of the tank)
- inserting the new mechanism in the hole and attaching the nut
- reattaching the supply line
- turning on the water supply
- adjusting the max fill level

Not too hard for even an amateur DIYer. Just be ready to quickly turn off the shutoff valve if there are any leaks (even a drop), and patiently redo any joints that are not absolutely watertight (the instructions will explain about teflon tape, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

In our situation, it turned out the high pitched noise was coming from the thin tube that carries the water to the top of the cistern and fills the tank. The tube had become slightly kinked. Straightening it eliminated the loud noise.

Answer (score 1):

I got mine to stop by reducing the water flow using the water shut-off (most often found below the tank and attached to the wall). I can only assume that the water pressure (from having the valve fully open) was too much for my toilets to handle. My toilets are now not only quiet but, fill faster.

Answer (score 0):

Great suggestion. The squealing was loud every flush. I took the rubber refill hose off the cistern and squeezed it up and down in case something was clogging it. Then I twisted the cap off the top of the valve a few times while cycling the lever. It did the trick. It flushes without squealing now!!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me for the whining toilet inlet valve problem. Basically the trick is to pass a high pressure air blast through the system, which is simply done by turning off the water supply to the house, then opening all cold taps around the house until no more water comes out - this lets air into the system. Then close all the taps, turn the water supply back on - then flush the toilet - wait for the bangs as air gets blasted through the cistern’s inlet valve. And with luck the whining will have disappeared!